# Can't import Svg icons in material-ui@next

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have upgraded material ui version to v1.0.0-beta.26. With this update I am facing module not found issue when I try to import  ActionCircle or any icon as like below.

```
Eg: import AccountCircle from 'material-ui-icons/AccountCircle';
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that you're missing the icons package. Install the material-ui-icons package with this command in terminal:

```
npm install material-ui-icons --save
```

Comment: Oh thank you. Got it. I never thought it’s a seperate package in latest version.